# Google Chrome Developer Toolbar says an image doesn't have a cache expiration, but it seems like it does

Tags: caching, google-chrome, http-headers, cache-control

An example, [Google's own logo](https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png)  If you go to either [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or the [URL of the image

and run a page audit using the Developer Toolbar, you'll get a message to take advantage of browser caching, viz. `The following resources are missing a cache expiration. Resources that do not specify an expiration may not be cached by browsers: logo3w.png`.

Then, if you look at the actual headers, e.g. [via](http://web.forret.com/tools/analyze.aspx?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen_com%2Fimages%2Fsrpr%2Flogo3w.png), they read:

```
* Content-Type = image/png
* Last-Modified = Fri, 05 Aug 2011 02:40:26 GMT
* Date = Fri, 30 Dec 2011 20:53:48 GMT
* Expires = Fri, 30 Dec 2011 20:53:48 GMT
* Cache-Control = private, max-age=31536000
* X-Content-Type-Options = nosniff
* Server = sffe
* Content-Length = 7007
* X-XSS-Protection = 1; mode=block
```

What's the deal?

**UPDATE** :: MattH points out that the `Expires` time is the same as the request.  True!  I think there's still a problem; check out [this image](http://s3.amazonaws.com/thesprouts-org/public/images/linen.jpg).

Comment: Maybe because `Expires` is the same date and time as the query, so the tool logically determines that it isn't being cached. Smart tool.

Comment: @MattH: Yep, except it still breaks on another example.  Check out [this image](http://s3.amazonaws.com/thesprouts-org/public/images/linen.jpg)

Comment: Which version of Google Chrome are you using? With 18.0.975.0 (Developer Build 114930), the linen.jpg results in only one violation for me, "The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime: linen.jpg". This is because the Cache-Control header contains max=600 which is only 10 minutes (and at least 1 month is expected.)

Comment: Still having the issue using 32.0.1700.102